# How are news apps updated?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do news apps get updated, with new news? Does the programmer/developer have to physically edit the source code each time, or is there a way that someone else could have "master control" of the app to update it without changing the source code? The reason I'm asking is because I want to make an iOS app for my fantasy league to keep updated on changes and trades etc...

Thanks

Comment: an app can download things via HTTP. That covers "news". But Apple forbids downloadable code, so you can basically only add new content, not new functions. (But you can turn on functions that you already thought of in advance)

Comment: Ok, but how would new content be added? So lets say that Mon. said Team 1 made a trade to Team 2, but then Tues. it would say Team 1 made a trade to Team 3.

Comment: You would have a list stored on a website (XML format... do you know about PLIST files?, database). You can also put pictures on a website and have the app download and place them in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: I'd recommend learning enough about iOS development that you can do one of the stackmob iOS tutorials... http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials

Comment: You definitely want to consider [RSS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial).  Here's another [RSS link](http://www.whatisrss.com/).

Comment: So basically I would use RSS to download information to the app from a website? But would that take me to the website, or would it just display the information from the website?